# Puppeteer: WebRTC statistics

Tags: webrtc, puppeteer

I am planning to use Puppeteer for WebRTC call. I hope it should be easy. I am not sure how do I collect statistics like WebRTC call is passed or failed, how many media packets (UDP packets exchanged), stun / turn pass fail, media parameters like jitter, delay etc.

Can somebody please help me to understand, using Puppeteer how can one collect WebRTC related statistics.

Comment: How would you collect WebRTC statistics without puppeteer?

Comment: may be chrome://webrtc-internals. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well known WebRTC test engine based on selenium and selenium grid called [KITE](https://github.com/webrtc/KITE). For references, and quick start you can check the simple `KITE-AppRTC-Test` implementation to see how they are collecting the stats, and show them. You might want to run the demos as well because it seems to have the results you are looking for.

Among many other approaches one might be -

- Collect WebRTC connection metrics by calling [getStats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getStats) API. What you see in [chrome://webrtc-internals](http://chrome://webrtc-internals/) is a visual representation of this getStats API that collects `getStats` snapshots in regular interval, and showing them after some post-processing.
- Collect getStats data from puppeteer [page.evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), send it to server and then analyse the data realtime or at the end of call based on your use case.

There are quite good amount of opensource work done by WebRTC experts on how you can collect WebRTC data, send them to server and represent them

- https://github.com/fippo/webrtc-externals
- https://github.com/fippo/webrtc-dump-importer
- https://github.com/fippo/dump-webrtc-event-log